# Python cancel async function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm try to do something like this

```
def noAsyncPrint(c):
    sleep(random.uniform(1,10))
    print(c)

chars = ['a','b','c']
for c in chars:
    noAsyncPrint(c)
```

getting this output

```
a, b, c
```

How I get some random order??
thank you :)

edit to be clear about my example
**It's just basic example for being clear, It should be random api request after doing few things **

Comment: There's no async function to cancel; it looks like you want to *run* three async functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ThreadPool` from [multiprocessing.pool](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) :

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from time import sleep
import random

def noAsyncPrint(c):
    sleep(random.uniform(1,10))
    print(c)

chars = ['a','b','c']
    
with ThreadPool(3) as p:
    p.map(noAsyncPrint, chars)
```

output:

```
a
c
b
```

the output is random, can be any combination

in the above code, you are using 3 threads that will execute your function `noAsyncPrint` in an asynchronous fashion so your output is random

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [asyncio library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). Checkout this [guide](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) for a nice walk-through. The following example uses the `gather()` function to schedule the `async_print()` in a concurrent fashion. I also added logging with time stamp to make the execution order visible:

```
import logging
import random
import asyncio

lgr = logging.getLogger('main')


async def async_print(c):
    tau = round(random.uniform(1,10))
    lgr.debug(f"async_print('%s'): - sleeping of %g sec ...", c, tau)
    await asyncio.sleep(tau)
    lgr.debug(f"async_print('%s'): ... done sleeping.", c)
    print(c)


async def main():
    chars = ['a','b','c']
    lgr.info("Creating futures... ")
    list_of_futures = [async_print(c_) for c_ in chars]
    lgr.debug("Calling futures concurrently ... ")
    await asyncio.gather(*list_of_futures)
    lgr.info(" ... done.")


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, datefmt="%H:%M:%S",
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)s[%(lineno)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s')
asyncio.run(main())
```

The output looks like this:

```
15:17:56 asyncio[59] DEBUG Using selector: EpollSelector
15:17:56 main[17] INFO Calling futures ... 

15:17:56 main[19] DEBUG Waiting for completion ... 
15:17:56 main[9] DEBUG async_print('a'): - sleeping of 9 sec ...
15:17:56 main[9] DEBUG async_print('b'): - sleeping of 9 sec ...
15:17:56 main[9] DEBUG async_print('c'): - sleeping of 1 sec ...
15:17:57 main[11] DEBUG async_print('c'): ... done sleeping.
c
a
b
15:18:05 main[11] DEBUG async_print('a'): ... done sleeping.
15:18:05 main[11] DEBUG async_print('b'): ... done sleeping.
15:18:05 main[21] INFO  ... done.
```

Note that the `print()` function does not always display the output immediately. The logging functions behave much better in that regard.

Comment: thank you for your comment.. but I'm actually using python 3.6 and the run support only from 3.7.. anyway nice to know there is different between the console and the logger.

Answer (score 0):

in the numpy library, there is a function for random order, called `np.random.suffle()`

```
import numpy as np # import the numpy lybrary

def noAsyncPrint(c):
    sleep(random.uniform(1,10))
    print(c)

chars = np.array(['a','b','c']) #make it a np array
random_chars = np.random.suffle(chars) # shuffle it!

for c in random_chars:
    noAsyncPrint(c)
```

Comment: look at my edit... anyway just random.shuffle(chars) will shuffle the chars array.